# Limit of floor function and sqrt

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is anyone able to help me with the following limit question
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{ \left\lfloor \sqrt{x}  \right\rfloor  }{ \sqrt{x} } $$

Comment: This limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use the fact that for any $y$, $y - 1 < \lfloor y \rfloor \le y$.